# Unclosed $ found at close group } and Unexpected close group } after $

Tags: errors

There is error message found on overleaf as follows:

unclosed $ found at close group }

unclosed $ found at close group }

unexpected close group } after $

unexpected close group } after $

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
   \caption{Computational time comparison for hybrid configuration}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{|>{$}c<{$}}|}
 \hline
 \multirow{2}[t 3]*{\textbf{wafer flow}} 
   &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{computational time (seconds)}}\\
 \cline{2-3}
   & \textbf{MIP II model} & \textbf{Z sequence}  \\
 \hline
 $[2]$  & 198 & 0.11 \\
 \hline
 $[3]$  & 204 & 0.11 \\
 \hline
 $[1,2]$  & 375 & 0.12\\
 \hline
 $[1,3]$  & 367 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,1]$  & 756 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,2]$  & 861 & 0.14\\
 \hline
 $[1,3,1]$  & 732 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,1,1]$  & 1288 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,3,1,1]$  & 1314 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,1,2]$  & 1538 & 0.15\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,2,1]$  & 1450 & 0.14\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,2,2]$  & 1444 & 0.14\\
 \hline
 $[1,3,2,1]$  & 1387 & 0.15\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,1,1,1]$  & 2381 & 0.13\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table_computational_time_hybrid} 
\end{table}
```

Can anyone let me know what needs to be revised for the line: \begin{tabular}{*{3}{|>{$}c<{$}}|} ?

Thank you.

Comment: To make your code compilable, the `array` and `multirow` packages must be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

To make the OP's code compilable, it's necessary to load the `array` and `multirow` packages as well.

The need for the `array` package arises because of the column type specification `>{$}c<{$}`, for automatic math mode. It's a bit mysterious as to why the column contents are supposed to be rendered in math mode. I wouldn't do it.

Do also consider giving the table a much more open "look" -- by omitting all vertical rules and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. I'd also avoid the rather vulgar-looking **boldfacing** of the header rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Computational time comparison for hybrid configuration}

\begin{tabular}{@{} ccc @{}}
 \toprule
 Wafer flow & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Computational time (seconds)}\\
 \cmidrule(l){2-3}
 & MIP II model & Z sequence \\ 
 \midrule {}
 [2]        &  198 & 0.11\\ {} 
 [3]        &  204 & 0.11\\ {} 
 [1,2]      &  375 & 0.12\\ {}
 [1,3]      &  367 & 0.13\\ {} 
 [1,2,1]    &  756 & 0.13\\ \addlinespace {}
 [1,2,2]    &  861 & 0.14\\ {} 
 [1,3,1]    &  732 & 0.13\\ {} 
 [1,2,1,1]  & 1288 & 0.13\\ {}
 [1,3,1,1]  & 1314 & 0.13\\ {}
 [1,2,1,2]  & 1538 & 0.15\\ \addlinespace {} 
 [1,2,2,1]  & 1450 & 0.14\\ {}
 [1,2,2,2]  & 1444 & 0.14\\ {}
 [1,3,2,1]  & 1387 & 0.15\\ {}
 [1,2,1,1,1]& 2381 & 0.13\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{table_computational_time_hybrid} 
\end{table}

\lipsum % filler text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's fix the main problems.

1. `caption` is incompatible with `IEEEtran`
2. You need `array` in order to use `>{...}`
3. You need `multirow` for `\multirow`.
4. `\label` should be just after `\caption` (or inside the argument thereof), the best place for maintenance.
5. use `siunitx` features for tabular data

Now your table would look

```
\begin{tabular}{| c | S[table-format=4.0] | S[table-format=1.2] |}
 \hline
 \multirow{2}[t 3]*{\textbf{wafer flow}}
   &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{computational time (seconds)}}\\
 \cline{2-3}
   & \textbf{MIP II model} & \textbf{Z sequence}  \\
 \hline
 $[2]$  & 198 & 0.11 \\
 \hline
 $[3]$  & 204 & 0.11 \\
 \hline
 $[1,2]$  & 375 & 0.12\\
 \hline
 $[1,3]$  & 367 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,1]$  & 756 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,2]$  & 861 & 0.14\\
 \hline
 $[1,3,1]$  & 732 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,1,1]$  & 1288 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,3,1,1]$  & 1314 & 0.13\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,1,2]$  & 1538 & 0.15\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,2,1]$  & 1450 & 0.14\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,2,2]$  & 1444 & 0.14\\
 \hline
 $[1,3,2,1]$  & 1387 & 0.15\\
 \hline
 $[1,2,1,1,1]$  & 2381 & 0.13\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

and the output would be

[image]

If I leave `caption` I get

[image]

which is definitely not what IEEE seems to want. On the other hand, they seem happy when math is typeset in Computer Modern and text in Times , so I also suggest to fix this issue.

[image]

However, this doesn't look good at all. First of all, the boldface headers clearly conflict with the caption style (small caps) and the vertical rules are really bad.

##### Final version

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{caption} % <--- not compatible with IEEEtran
\usepackage{array}% <--- for the >{...}x<{...} syntax
%\usepackage{multirow}% <--- for \multirow (but you never need it)
\usepackage{siunitx}% <--- for tabular data
\usepackage{booktabs}% <--- for better tables

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Computational time comparison for hybrid configuration}
\label{table_computational_time_hybrid} 

\begin{tabular}{ @{} c S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=1.2] @{} }
\toprule
Wafer flow & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Computational time (s)} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
& {MIP II model} & {Z sequence} \\
\midrule
 $[2]$  & 198 & 0.11 \\
 $[3]$  & 204 & 0.11 \\
 $[1,2]$  & 375 & 0.12\\
 $[1,3]$  & 367 & 0.13\\
 $[1,2,1]$  & 756 & 0.13\\
 $[1,2,2]$  & 861 & 0.14\\
 $[1,3,1]$  & 732 & 0.13\\
 $[1,2,1,1]$  & 1288 & 0.13\\
 $[1,3,1,1]$  & 1314 & 0.13\\
 $[1,2,1,2]$  & 1538 & 0.15\\
 $[1,2,2,1]$  & 1450 & 0.14\\
 $[1,2,2,2]$  & 1444 & 0.14\\
 $[1,3,2,1]$  & 1387 & 0.15\\
 $[1,2,1,1,1]$  & 2381 & 0.13\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]